# kineticjs image backgrounds not transparent

Tags: transparency, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have some images that are .png's with transparent backgrounds however, when they are added to the stage they have white backgrounds. Am i missing a trick here?

Each image is added like so:

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var book = new Image();

book.onload=function () {
bookImg = new Kinetic.Image ({ x: 885, y: 780, offset: [85.5, 106], image:book, name:book, opacity: 0, /*scale:{x:0.5, y:0.5}*/ });
layer.add(bookImg);
stage.add(layer);
}
book.src = "images/book.png";
```

is it that the layer itself is what's creating the white background? 
a little confused!

Comment: Really need an answer to this question guys...

Driving me a bit crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Cant it be that you have to set the background to transparent? Not only the picture itself but the image-object containing the image. Maybe the layer aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to set the opacity on a Kinetic.Image() object. If you want it to be invisible, either initially or after being placed, simply use hide() (and subsequently show() to re-show it). Or set visible to false in the parameters. The minimum needed to place an image on the stage looks like this:

```
var image = new Kinetic.Image({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    image: imageObj,
    width: 300,
    height: 120
  });
layer.add(image);
layer.draw();
```

This assumes your layer has already been added to a Kinetic.Stage() and the image has loaded ( imageObj.onload = function(){} ). Including a name is fine, the offset and opacity (and even scale) are valid key/value pairs for parameters but not really necessary when creating the image. These can always be set after the image has been added to the layer as well (using one of the many setters in the KineticJS library).

I'd try using a minimalist approach to see if the image shows up as intended first, then go from there.